# Reactjs call arrow function in an arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have a problem with the arrow function in my React project.

The class looks like this:

```
f1() { 
// sth...
}

f2 = (a) => () => { /* sth */ }
f3 = (b) => () => {
   this.f1();
   this.f2();
}
```

Why the function f2 is not being called? F1 is ok but f2 seems to have a problem with context? How to solve it? I need to call the same function(f2) in another place where it works (onClick event). I guess there is a problem with 'this' that is auto binded but I don't know how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: `f2 = (a) => () => { /* sth */ }` This is creating a function returning a function. You have to call it with `f2()()`. Edit : made an answer for easier reading.

Comment: No, this is not a context problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function `f2` is indeed beeing called, but returns another function.

```
f2 = (a) => () => { /* sth */ }
```

this is equivalent to :

```
f2 = (a) => {
    return () => { /* sth */ }
}
```

So to call `/* sth */`, you have to use this :

```
f2()()
```

Because `f2()` returns your second function (the inner one).

Answer (score 2):

Function f3 is a function that returns another function and in order to invoke it, you need to write it like

```
f3 = (b) => () => {
   this.f1();
   this.f2();
}

this.f3()()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.f3(1);
  }

  f1() { 
    console.log('calling f1');
  }

  f2 = (a) => { 
    console.log('calling f2 ' + a);
  }

  f3 = (b) => {
   this.f1();
   this.f2('text');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jonas W. and @Seblor, you're creating functions returning functions. Instead use the syntax below:

```
f1() { 
// sth...
}

f2 = (a) => { /* sth */ }
f3 = (b) => {
   this.f1();
   this.f2();
}
```